# The type Database cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, oracle11g

after running the project i got this error.I added remote oracle connection string into web.config file. I didn't download oracle developer tool for visual studio 2017. I am using oracle 11g client and visual studio 2017 64x ,dot.net framework 4. Anybody knows anyway to solve this.Sorry for image edit.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
        DbProviderFactory DatabaseFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

        using (Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            db.ConnectionString = connectionString;

            db.Open();

            TestContext.WriteLine("Connection established : " + db.State);
            db.Close();
        }
```

Title `Creating the DbProviderFactory and DbConnection` may be helpful to you on this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory

Comment: thanks for reply :) . let me try this way . do i need to download oracle developer tool for visual studio? any info on this . i am fresher on this .

Comment: @ratna you're welcome. For testing purposes you need one of IDE tools, at least Oracle developer. There are better ones on the market also.

Comment: i found that dataprovider is System.Data.OracleClient in my project . so my question is if i apply above code that will be ok? or do i need to import Oracle.DataAccess.Client provider means oracle developer tool? i am very much new to this . so may be my question is a bit stupid :(

Comment: @ratna no, you don't need oracle's sql developer to import Oracle.DataAccess.Client, they're irrelevant. As i said before, the IDE is only for needed during DDL and DML tests.

Comment: thanks for the reply again :) . now it's clear to me . thanks :)